alt-< shortcuts not working under KDE Plasma
I've recently switched back to KDE Plasma with KWin from Qtile. After making the switch, I found that the Alt + < and Alt + > shortcuts, used to jump to beginning/end of input in Emacs-like environments, are not working.
The keys don't register at all, either in Emacs (windowed mode) or in a terminal app. (It also doesn't appear in xev.) My usual assumption here would be that the window manager is capturing them as a shortcut. However, I can't find any mapping of these keys in the system settings menu.
The issue only just appeared, and the only change I've made is switching back to KWin. Thus, I'm pretty sure this is the source of the issue.
Any idea what could be causing this?
UPDATE: I've used this technique to find out which client is grabbing that keybind. It's kglobalaccel5, which is what you would expect if it's a problem with global keybinds. However, it's still not clear where the configuration for this is.

After further investigation here, I found a reference to a known issue: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=365255
This affects users on X11 who are using a non-QWERTY keyboard layout. It leads to kglobalaccel mixing up keys from QWERTY vs. the active layout. In this case, I was able to work around the issue by removing most other bindings on alt or alt-shift keys.

You said you checked within the system settings menu. Can you check for any config files that would affect Qtile? https://docs.qtile.org/en/latest/manual/config/keys.html
ALT is known as mod1 or can also be mapped to something else in the EzKey.modifier_keys dictionary.
When something is controlling a keystroke, it won't be visible to xev.

I am currently not using qtile. Previously I was using qtile and it worked fine; I just switched back to kwin (for unrelated reasons) and it's broken.
